# Checking E-Mail existence in the JSON server using React JS

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-hook-form

I am creating a registration page using `React JS`. I have created a form that takes all the input from the user and stored this data to the JSON server using Axios. There is a field name as email `name= "email"` in the form and ***I want to check whether this email exists or not in the server while storing the whole form data***.
I am using a `react-hook-form` for this page.

Below are my `users` data in the db.json file.

```
{
 "users": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "email": "subro@gmail.com"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "email": "raja@gmail.com"
    }
  ]
}
```

The below code is for posting the form data to the JSON server and also checking the email existence but didn't work.

```
function LoginFile() {
  const { register, handleSubmit, errors } = useForm();

  const checkEmail = (getdata) => {
    console.log(getdata);
// need logic for checking email existence if exist stop posting and 
// else post the data to the server 
  };
  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    console.log(data);
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:4000/users")
      .then((res) => checkEmail(res.data));

    axios.post("http://localhost:4000/users", data).then((res) => {
      console.log(res.data);
    });
  };
return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      Email <input type="email" name="email" ref={register} />
      {errors.email && "Please enter email"}      
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  );
}
export default LoginFile;
```

How to check whether the email exists or not before posting it to the JSON Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  const checkEmail = (serverUsers,formData) => {
   const user = serverUsers.find(user => user.email === formData.email); // extract the email from the formData
    if (user) return user;
  };
  const onSubmit = async (formData) => {
       
        const user = await axios
          .get("http://localhost:4000/users")
          .then((res) => checkEmail(res.data,formData));

        if (user) alert("email exists");  // do whatever you want here with the existence user store.
        else
         await axios.post("http://localhost:4000/users", data).then((res) => {
          console.log(res.data);
        });
      };
```

Answer (score 1):

You can go through these steps.

1. First save your email data in a state.You have a functional component so useState will be good.

   ```
   const [Email, setEmail] = useState("")
   ```
2. After setting up and saving your state value coming from the input.You can use an onChange function

   ```
   setEmail(e.target.value);
   ```
3. You can hit up your handleSubmit function which will come back with all the user's data

   ```
    const handleSubmit = e => {
          e.preventDefault();
        axios
          .get("http://localhost:4000/users")
          .then((res) => checkEmail(res.data));
      };
   ```
4. Now in checkEmail function use JavaScript Array includes() Method which will check for your email.If it exists will show an alert otherwise submits it.

   ```
   const checkEmail = (getdata) => {
        console.log(getdata);
        if(getdata.includes(Email)){
            alert("Cannot post because of duplicate Email")
        }else{
            axios.post("http://localhost:4000/users", data).then((res) => {
            console.log(res.data);
        });
        }
      };
   ```

Comment: Welcome brother